# Http-Method changes from POST to OPTIONS when changing Content-Type

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-closure, plovr

I am using closure library to do a simple POST. I think XhrIo should work because from my machine when I use any other rest client ,like Firefox browser app RESTClient or Chrome's Simple Rest Client , I can make POST request to the server and content type is application/json.

But from my application I am unable to make a post.
I am using the following code

```
xhr = new goog.net.XhrIo;
xhr.send('http://myhost:8181/customer/add','POST', goog.json.serialize(data));
```

If I leave the headers default, I get this

> ```
> Encoding: UTF-8
> Http-Method: POST
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
> ```

If I try to change the header by passing `{'content-type':'application/json'}` as 4th parameter, header changes to

> Http-Method: OPTIONS
>    Content-Type:

Shouldn't I be able to change headers appropriately with Closure library just as RESTClient does with XMLHttpRequest using JQuery ?

How else can the header be altered to make it appear like this

> ```
> Encoding: UTF-8
> Http-Method: POST
> Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
> ```

Appreciate any help
Eddie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you add a header to an XHR object, most browsers will do a preflight request, which is the `OPTIONS` method that you are seeing. There is not a way to circumvent this if you are adding custom headers, unfortunately. The `POST` will be sent after the `OPTIONS`.

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Preflighted_requests) explains the `OPTIONS` request a bit. [I ran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199426/jquery-cors-json-without-padding-and-authentication-issues) into issues with the preflight a while back, if that is any help.

If you have specific issues with the `OPTIONS` request you should edit your question to include them; otherwise, this is expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks Achal , this was useful information. Just wonder how RESTClient (http://code.google.com/p/restclient/source/browse/extension/chrome/content/restclient.js) manage to do it ? Is it because they pass this passwordObject: null ?

Comment: I don't really know, to be honest. What is the issue you have? Is the `OPTIONS` request getting denied? If so, what HTTP code are you receiving?

Comment: @AchalDave the content length is coming 0 when POST is automatically getting converted to OPTIONS

Answer (score 2):

FWIW mine also failed to update the type when I specified...

```
{'content-type':'application/json'}
```

However, if I corrected the case to

```
{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
```

... it worked.

Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pass `Content-Type` on `authorization` request it will convert `POST` method to `OPTIONS` method so while we are use **ouath** and passing **authorization token** that time do not required `Content-Type`.

So **do not pass** `Content-Type` on all `authorization` request it won't change your method `POST` to `OPTIONS`

Comment: can you explain more about it? My method change to Options from POST when I'm posting a request to an API URL