# How to access SSL enabled WCF service from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wcf

I want to access a SSL enabled WCF service from asp.net 2.0 application. Site was hosted on IIS 7.

**Here is the Code**

```
function getCourse() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://website.com/service.svc/task",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 7000,
        username: "someusername",
        password: "somepassword",
        success: function (data) { alert("success"); },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) { alert("error"); }
    });
};
```

I get 401 error, I didn't do any configuration in iis or webconfig related to the ssl access? Am I missing anything here? or the fact that I'm using asp.net 2.0 application cause the error?

Comment: Does your WCF web service require additional headers for verification and authentication?

Comment: Yes, username and password. Which I pass it on the jQuery function.

Comment: You can change the datatype from json to jsonp and that should help you access the webservice on a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you might need to add additional header in your jquery ajax function, like following one:

```
headers: { 
    Authenticate: Basic username:password (to base64)
}
```

or

```
beforeSend: setHeaders

function setHeader(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic base64.encode(username:password)');
}
```

According to Wiki, 401 Unauthorized is defined as

> Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication
>   is required and has failed or has not yet been provided.
>
> The response must include a **WWW-Authenticate header** field
>   containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. See Basic
>   access authentication and Digest access authentication.

Reference
HTTP status codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
Basic access authentication: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: I did try with following code but no luck. header: { "Authorization": "Basic username:password" }

Comment: I did but gives me js error! EX: "Authorization": "Basic " + Base64.encode("username:password")

Comment: maybe try another approach, create following function setHeader(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', 'Basic Base64.encode('username:password')');
} and add setHeader to beforeSend

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this post and that perhaps would give you something - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9570852/786796

Comment: I guess the issue is, I'm running on the localhost. I will try to run on the hosted server.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I guess I found the answer in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327218/access-control-allow-origin-not-allowed-by

Comment: No worries. Glad that you found your answer yourself.