# setRequestHeader not working, I want to set my header and then make a GET request in ajax in Amazon EC2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, xmlhttprequest

**I am trying to make a GET request and for this I am supposed to send header values, I Have tried the methods below. This API call seems to be working fine in POSTMAN extension I use to test the API's**

```
       
        $.ajax({
            url: "requested url",
            type: 'GET',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('setHeader', '12345');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Failed");
            },
        });
```

**AJAX request seems to be working fine, but the moment I add a header via beforeSend or headers, an OPTIONS pre-flight request is made and the GET request is aborted.**

**I have also tried setting the headers using $.ajaxSetup();**

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('setHeader', '12345');
            }
        });


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "requested url"
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function () {
            alert("Failed");
        });
```

**Request headers :**

```
Request URL:requested url
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, setHeader
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
```

**Response headers :**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With,setHeader
Access-Control-Allow-Method:GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:*
```

**I get this error in my console :**

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load** "requested url". **Invalid HTTP status code 404**

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your problem is jsonp related. Just guesing here.
[what-is-jsonp-all-about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)
[can-i-set-headers-in-cross-domain-json-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153569/can-i-set-headers-in-cross-domain-json-requests<br)

Check your server headers aswell.