# Send Headers in Cross domain request From Ajax

Tags: jquery, jsonp, request-headers

I need to pass `UserID` as request header but I am not able to pass it with the request headerin the cross domain url.

Below is the screenshot for the Ajax Request in which I am getting the `Accept-Control-Request-Header : UserID` but when I pass it using the [$.ajax() headers](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) option; it not not shown in the `Headers Tab` of Firebug

[image]

I also tried the `beforeSend` option but no progress.

Below is the sample code which I have used,

```
headers: {'UserID': 12345 },
dataType: 'jsonp',
crossdomain: true,
beforeSend: function (request) {                
      request.withCredentials = true;
      request.setRequestHeader("UserID", "1");
      request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
      request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
},
```

And I have referred all the below SO Urls,

1. [jQuery JSONP ajax, authentication header not being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433556/jquery-jsonp-ajax-authentication-header-not-being-set)
2. [Can I set headers in cross domain json requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153569/can-i-set-headers-in-cross-domain-json-requests)
3. [Modify HTTP Headers for a JSONP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350778/modify-http-headers-for-a-jsonp-request)

Is there a way to show the request headers in the `Firebug Headers tab` or it is the Server Side Security which blocks the request header.

Comment: I think, it seems not possible to send headers like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution.

There was no error at my end(client end). Actually the error was  from server side, which was not allowing me to send headers. Allowing cross origin request parameters at server end the problem is solved.

Comment: What needs to be changed at the server to allow them?

Comment: Server was provided by client, so I don't know what changes are made by him. But http://enable-cors.org/server.html might help you for this.