# Allow headers in cross-domain ajax request

Tags: ajax, apache, http, cors

The first Ajax request receives a response, but not the second which includes a header.  How can I allow headers to be included in a cross-domain Ajax request.

Note - I expect I need to make a server-side change, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/32140436/1032531 also says so, but doesn't say how to make those changes.  Also, I am not looking for a jQuery only solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'http://otherdomain.example.com/ajax.php',
                })
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'http://otherdomain.example.com/ajax.php',
                    headers: {"X-Test-Header": "test-value"},
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body></body> 
</html>
```

FF response to the second Ajax request:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://otherdomain.example.com/ajax.php.
>   (Reason: missing token 'x-test-header' in CORS header
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).

Chrome responds to the second as:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://otherdomain.example.com/ajax.php.
>   Request header field X-Test-Header is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. Apache is set up
>   as

follows:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that each header must explicitly be listed and I added `x-test-header` to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-test-header, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of this error by using a .htaccess rule. Just create a `.htaccess` file.on the home directory (or append these lines to it if you already have one)

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

This will globally allow cross orgin. If you want for only one page you can use

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>
```

At the top of the page

Comment: Thanks, but as seen in my original post, I already was doing so.  It is the header which isn't going through.