# Header is not getting passed to server using ajax JSONP request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am requesting cross origin domain  and adding custom headers. But header is not getting in server side.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " +($("#accesstoken").val()));
    },
    url: myJSonServer + encodeURI(operation),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    success: callback,
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown); }
});
```

In server side added:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Request-Method: *
```

Comment: Have a look in the console. You likely die in the preflight OPTIONS call

Comment: your server must send a Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, for more info  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153569/can-i-set-headers-in-cross-domain-json-requests)

Comment: From memory I think Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is not allowed when you send credentials in the request. You have to specify an explicit origin. You can google to check that, but I'm fairly sure.

Comment: It was due to preflight OPTIONS issue. Solved. Thanks