# CORS request not working when sending authorization headers

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, cors, ionic2

EDIT: Kevin B answered my question in a comment below. I added some logic to send a 200 request if an OPTIONS http request hit my API to fix the problem. Here is the code:

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
  res.send(200);
}
else {
  next();
}
};

router.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Original Question:
I currently am trying to get an Ionic 2 application running on my localhost to be able to send data to an Express 4 application. It works when I send requests without an authorization header. However, once I added auth headers, my API began to throw errors. I have done my research and have tried to implement what I found here: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15254158/5379931.

However, I am getting errors still. If I set Access-Control-Allow-Origin like this:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100");
```

I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. Response to preflight request doesn't pass
access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
'http://localhost:8100/' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin
'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If I set my Access-Control-Allow-Origin header like this:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100/");
```

I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is
therefore   not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

Here is the rest of my express 4 code that is relevant:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
});
```

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between what you claim you’re setting and what error message you get when you do. The first message you cite says, “The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
'http://localhost:8100/'”, so that indicates your server’s configured to send the value `http://localhost:8100/`, with the trailing slash. There’s no other way that trailing slash would get added to the value. Yet you claim when you see that message, you have the server configured to send the value `http://localhost:8100`, with no trailing slash. That makes no sense. I think you need to doublecheck

Comment: To be clear: The server needs to be configured to send the value `http://localhost:8100` without the trailing slash—because origin values do not contain paths, and the `Origin` request header the browser is sending is `http://localhost:8100` (with no trailing slash), so your Access-Control-Allow-Origin must either *exactly* match that or else must just be `*`.

Comment: you probably forgot to actually *respond* to the options request. you did set the headers, but if you don't respond it'l go to your error handler.

Comment: @KevinB Yes I think the fact that I was not responding was the problem. I added some logic to send a 200 request if an OPTIONS http request hit my API. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to respond to the options request. By not responding, it will go to your error handler and be dealt with as if it were an error.

Just send a 200 status within your .use if it is an options request so that it doesn't reach your error handler.

Comment: This is the solution to my problem.