# Request Header missing authorisation - Codeigniter rest

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, jwt

I am creating a restful services with Codeigniter rest server and firebase php-jwt.
Created an api to return list of operator. To access this api client has to send token in headers. Sample request is -

> GET /index.php/operators/prepaid HTTP/1.1
>   Host: testing.mydomain.in
>   Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjExNTIxNCIsImlhdCI6MTUxNzk4MjU1NywiZXhwIjoxNTE4MDAwNTU3fQ.PZYh3OlSsKGo_ihPPSm7RrU5BbTNaeTN1fKlNcOZ2r4
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Postman-Token: 933f3b1d-7934-d30a-11bf-f80f3912f433

controller code

```
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
class Operators extends REST_Controller 
{
    private $_payload;

    public function __construct($config = 'rest')
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
        $token = $this->input->get_request_header('Authorization');
        if(!$token) {
            $output = array("Error" => "Access Denied");
            $this->response($output, REST_Controller::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        try {
            $this->_payload = JWT::decode($token, $this->config->item('jwt_secret_key'),array('HS256'));
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $output = array("Error" => $ex->getMessage());
            $this->response($output, REST_Controller::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        $this->load->model('Operators_Data');
    }       

    public function prepaid_get()
    { 
        $operators = $this->Operators_Data->getOperatorsByService(1);
        $this->response($operators);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following result

```
{
     "Error": "Access Denied"
}
```

Returned from controller constructor if token is not present.But i am sending the token in header authorisation.

This is working on my local host (it returns list of operator). but when i 
trying from testing server it always returning "Access Denied".

**UPDATE :** Pretty sure that server is ignoring "Authorization" header.

Also tried with

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

Settings in .htaccess

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you get for all headers? http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Comment: {
    "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.1.1",
    "Host": "testing.mydomain.in",
    "Postman-Token": "e33c8281-15e0-46b9-88c1-26597780e33c",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
}

Comment: So your Authorization header is missing. Are you for sure including it in your Postman request, because it doesn't appear that you are.

Comment: I am setting in header tab with key "Authorization" and auth returned token as value. Not in Authorisation tab

Comment: Check this post if its gonna be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253957/why-my-server-ignores-the-authentication-headers-from-an-ajax-request

Comment: hey @TheMegamind How did you solve it?

Answer (score 7):

Adding

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

at the top of the `.htaccess` file solved it in my case

Comment: After adding that code to .htaccess it still doesn't work. So i resolved that by adding that httpd-xampp.conf (if you use XAMPP) under <VirtualHost *:80> , and that work for me.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
     

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
 
    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

 SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</IfModule>